# Custom identity sequence in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

It's my first time incorporating a custom identity sequence in one of my projects. I have a stored procedure for inserting new records into the database. I have this but not too sure how to incorporate it into my existing stored procedure.

Here's the script that I want to add into my stored procedure:

```
PatientID AS '23-' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(PatientID AS NVARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED
```

Trying to add into this section of my stored procedure:

```
    @GroundServiceDate NVARCHAR(100),
    @GroundInvoice NVARCHAR(100),
    @GroundPaymentMethod NVARCHAR(50),
    @GroundVoucherId NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PatientID AS '23-' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(PatientID AS NVARCHAR(3)),3) PERSISTED

    INSERT INTO tblReferrals (PatientID, ReferralNumber, AssignedReviewer, S
```

Comment: similar questions asked many times on SO

Comment: Perhaps if you try to explain what you want to accomplish we can help you get there. As it is `PatientID AS '23-' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(PatientID AS NVARCHAR(3)),3) PERSISTED` doesn't make much sense. Creating a column alias (`AS`) from an expression that involves creating a 6- to 9-character string and taking the right 3 characters. All without a data source for the `PatientID` that you `cast`.

Comment: I apologize. This is what I have so far that is working thanks to @squirrel. My main problem was just the syntax and how to incorporate it into my stored procedure. PatientID is a column on one of my tables, which auto increments whenever new object is inputted.

Comment: Use FORMAT function to fill your string id with zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a string variable inside your stored procedure to store that calculation into, and then use it in the INSERT?

```
DECLARE @patientID NVARCHAR(15);
SET @patientID = 
'23-' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(PatientID AS NVARCHAR(3)),3)

INSERT INTO tblReferrals (PatientID, ReferralNumber, AssignedReviewer,...) 
                  VALUES (@patientID,...);
```

Comment: Where does `PatientID` get a value from in your `set` statement?

Comment: Theres a column in my table labeled PatientID which auto increments every time user submits.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your assistance. Thanks to your response I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @spades0001 Lovely to know that `PatientID` is likely to be an `identity` column in a table somewhere. How does `SET @patientID = '23-' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(PatientID AS NVARCHAR(3)),3)` find that table?

Comment: As y say : *DECLARE @patientID NVARCHAR(15) = CONCAT('23-' FORMAT('0000000000', PatientID)

INSERT INTO tblReferrals (PatientID, ReferralNumber, AssignedReviewer,...) 
                  VALUES (@patientID,...);*